# views must be a callable or a list\tuple in case of include

Tags: django

Django==1.10.5
Login.
I have made login form, then write these codes and wanted to run the server

```
Urls.py:

    urlpatterns = [
        #previous login view
        #url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
        #login/logout urls
        url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

        url(r'^login/$', 'login', name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
        url(r'^logout-thenlogin/$','django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', 
            name='logout_then_login'),

]

Views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import LoginForm



def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

When i wanted to runserver- i got this message:
Views must be a callable or a list\tuple in case of include

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.10+ no longer allows you to specify views as a string (e.g. 'myapp.views.home') in your URL patterns.

The solution is to update your urls.py to include the view callable. This means that you have to import the view in your urls.py. If your URL patterns don't have names, then now is a good time to add one, because reversing with the dotted python path no longer works.

```
urlpatterns = [
        #previous login view
        #url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
        #login/logout urls
        url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

        url(r'^login/$', your_app_name.views.user_login, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', django.contrib.auth.views.logout, name='logout'),
        url(r'^logout-thenlogin/$', django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login, 
            name='logout_then_login'),

]
```

Comment: Actually i did not get, sorry i am beginner -that is why i could not get u.  should i import user_login from views?

Comment: yes you have to import the user_login from view or u can just write url(r'^login/$', appname.views.user_login, name='login')

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    #previous login view
    #url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    #login/logout urls
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    #url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
    #url(r'^logout-then-login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout_then_login'),

Comment: when i uncomment logout and logout-thenlogin-i have the same problem

Comment: Thanks Rohit Chopra. i have made as u wrote.